# Writing Powershell in jenkins File or direct in jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and I would like to use it to automate some tasks. the Powershell plugin has been installed and confnigured and currently works. I already have scripts which takes care of my tasks, lets say 12 of them so 12 script files. I have some questions on how best to integrate this into a Jenkins pipeline.

I want to know whether its better to leave my Powershell Scripts as individual files or perhaps place them in a repository and get Jenkins to pull them down and run them or copy the contents of the Powershell files directly into Jenkins and run them from there instead of calling the individual file.

Secondly, my scripts needs to pass values between them. Is it possible to have a Jenkins pipeline which calls multiple Powershell script files for different taks, can i pass values from task 1 to take 2 etc ?

I want to know the best way to proceed, examples of calling Ps script files and returning values into Jenkins variables would be good, either caling a PS file or running Powershell code directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you store the PowerShell scripts depends a lot on the details and preference. Personally, I would put them right in the Jenkinsfile if I only needed them at this one place. If I needed them in different places, I'd put them in Git.

You can return the stdout of a PowerShell command, store it in a variable and use that in another PowerShell script like so:

```
def msg = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: 'Write-Output "PowerShell is mighty!"')
powershell "use $msg here"
```

Problem here is that you only can get strings out of it and no PowerShell objects. You can also return the exit code and store it in a variable.

For more information, see [this](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I do have a question, the example you provided, if its a piece of code with 300 lines. How will this work ? Also, if I was calling a PS file, how will it work ? How about multiple variables

Comment: 300 lines of code might be a problem since the stdout of all the lines will be stored in the variable. Either you splitt them into smaller pieces or supress their output.
Calling a PS file should work the same way as calling it on your local machine (given that it is present in the current directory).

For multiple variables you must split the script in smaller blocks and use each output as its on variable.

I'm no PS expert, I'm mostly using sh. Sorry if a cannot help

Answer (score 0):

I put all my powershell code directly into the pipeline. But its always around max. 10 lines of ps code.